# Push Notification not working on Android with Phonegap 2.2.0

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I am working on push notification for android cordova 2.2.0

I Have followed all the instructions listed on the [PushPlugin page](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), but when ever i try to register a device i get an error and the app just closes/shutdowns this happens when am testing on my android phone

On the android virutal machine, i get the following from logcat:

```
02-19 21:48:31.152: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(383): Ignore this event
02-19 21:48:31.302: V/PushPlugin(383): execute: action=register
02-19 21:48:31.322: V/PushPlugin(383): execute: data=        [{"senderID":391440660838,"ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}]
02-19 21:48:31.322: V/PushPlugin(383): execute: jo=        {"senderID":391440660838,"ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}
02-19 21:48:31.352: D/AndroidRuntime(383): Shutting down VM
02-19 21:48:31.352: W/dalvikvm(383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught         exception (group=0x40015560)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383): java.lang.ClassCastException:         java.lang.Long
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at                 com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin.execute(PushPlugin.java:63)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at         org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:61)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at         org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:224)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at         org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:43)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:213)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at         android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:566)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at         dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 21:49:32.252: I/Process(383): Sending signal. PID: 383 SIG: 9
```

I have rechecked everything on the page and followed instructions but still the app shuts down when i try to register a device.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is :

> 02-19 21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:         java.lang.Long 02-19
>   21:48:31.392: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at
>   com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin.execute(PushPlugin.java:63)

PushPlugin.java:63 is:

```
gSenderID = (String) jo.get("senderID");
```

It looks like that line is trying to cast a Long to a String. I think the problem is here:

```
execute: jo=        {"senderID":391440660838,"ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}
```

I don't know how the `jo` JSON is initialized, but it should probably be changed to:

```
execute: jo=        {"senderID":"391440660838","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}
```

You should wrap the number with quotes.

EDIT:

Looking at the instructions in the link you posted, you definitely forgot the quotes around the sender ID:

```
if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
{
    pushNotification.register(
        successHandler,
        errorHandler, {
            "senderID":"replace_with_sender_id",
            "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
        });
}
```